# How to extract value from xml based on leading text using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have an xml response in the following format

```
...
<field>
    <fieldType>DOCUMENT</fieldType>
    ...
    <fieldId>12345</fieldId>
    <id>21345</id>
    <isActive>F</isActive>
    ....
</field>
<field>
    <fieldType>FOLDER</fieldType>
    ...
    <fieldId>15345</fieldId>
    <id>11345</id>
    <isActive>T</isActive>
    ....
</field>
<field>
    <fieldType>DOCUMENT</fieldType>
    ...
    <fieldId>98765</fieldId>
    <id>57689</id>
    <isActive>T</isActive>
    ....
</field>
...
```

There are multiple such values in the xml. I need to extract only the fieldId 
1. which is active i.e., T
2. which is of fieldType DOCUMENT.

I tried the following regex,

```
<fieldType>DOCUMENT</fieldType>.+?<fieldId>(.+?)</fieldId>.+?<isActive>T</isActive>
```

But this is extracting the 1st occurrence of fieldId, 12345 (even though it is not active) instead of 98765

P.s: I am trying to use this regex

Comment: Why can't you use a proper XML parser and have to rely on regex?

Answer (score 0):

An xml parser is probably a better solution. However based on your question this seems to achieve the desired output.

`<fieldType>DOCUMENT<\/fieldType>\n.*\n.*<fieldId>(.*)<\/fieldId>.*\n.*\n.*<isActive>T<\/isActive>/g`

Try it here! https://regexr.com/3krn4